# HAProxy live injection

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, load-balance

I would ask you if HAProxy load balancer can be live injectioned (reconfigured without restarting the balancer) without losing connections.

Answer (score 1):

Reconfiguring haproxy can be done by modifying the configuration file and then sending `SIGHUP` to the running process. Usually, you can use `/etc/init.d/haproxy reload`. This should do graceful reload and not drop your connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable/enable servers using the socket file.. but I don't think you are able to add remove servers. The newer versions of haproxy when you send a `SIGHUP` to it will gracefuly reload and not even reset the stats when you change the config.